# Make cursor not scroll past line in Sublime text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

Is there any way to make sure that when holding down right/left arrow key, the cursor never goes past the current line? Just like Vim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the following to your user keybindings:

```
{ "keys": ["left"], "command": "noop", "context": [
        { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_match", "operand": "^$" }
    ],
},
{ "keys": ["right"], "command": "noop", "context": [
        { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_match", "operand": "^$" }
    ]
},
```

This will override the default behavior for the left arrow key when the caret is at the start of the line, and for the right arrow key when the caret is at the end of the line, to call the `noop` command, which will perform no operation, instead of the usual movement command.